# How do I track down the string that is causing this mysql exception?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, utf-8

I have been brought on to fix some issues with a peice of software, I have never used mysql before, and when running one of the python scripts that interacts with mysql I get a error.

Here is the Traceback:

```
Assign scans to examsets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyse.py", line 16, in <module>
    scans.AssignScansToExamSets()
  File "/home/connor/billing/billing/scans.py", line 1190, in AssignScansToExamSets
    scanTable = scanTable, examSetsTable = examSetsTable)
  File "/home/connor/billing/billing/funcautoassign.py", line 234, in AutoAssignScansToExamSets
    debug = examSetsTable.Flush(log, startTime)
  File "/home/connor/billing/billing/scandb.py", line 1175, in Flush
    examSetIds = self.db.multiple_insert("examset", vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/db.py", line 840, in multiple_insert
    self._db_execute(db_cursor, q1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/db.py", line 587, in _db_execute
    out = cur.execute(query, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Invalid utf8 character string: 'A1421C'
```

How do I find where that string is? And any advice on fixing this issue?
The mysql data base is currently using latin1 as the charset, which as far as I can tell should be fine with utf8 stuff. How can you set a mysql database to import into a particular charset?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and logging the values you are sending to the database? `scandb.Flush()` looks like a good candidate, what's in `vals` there?

Comment: I'm trying to find out, vals is a list of various values, some are time and date, one is a hash, I think the others are text, the issue being I didn't make this and I'm trying to figure out the maze I was left with.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details. Also, that doesn't tell me anything about what those variables contain.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what they actually are.